# Is there a way to keep the height of two columns with jquery on a website while using bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap website that I've created that has two columns, the left is the menu navigation and the right is the content. In the background of the left column I have a background that I would like to be the height of the content on any of the given pages. I added this snippet of jquery in my site and it works on the full browser window just fine

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        equalHeight($("div#col1, div#col2"));

        function equalHeight(group) {
            tallest = 0;
            group.each(function() {
                thisHeight = $(this).height();
                if(thisHeight > tallest) {
                    tallest = thisHeight;
                }
            });
            group.height(tallest);
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="middle">
     <div id="col1"></div>
     <div id="col2"></div>
</div>
```

But when you start to scale down the page for mobile it throws the footer content into the middle of the page and adds a second scroll bar?

I'm curious if I'm able to use something similar to this code that is bootstrap friendly
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a faux column by giving `.middle` a background that looks like it is applied to `#col1`

Check out this article on **[faux columns](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns)**